# Javascript: when the word is clicked 5 times, another word shows below

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to conduct a script that I would like to work as follows:

a sentence shows up,and each time the user clicks on the sentence, another sentence shows up. there are five sentence options and each time the user clicks the sentence a 'random' sentence shows. Then after it is clicked 5 times, a link beneath appears. I would like for this all to be apart of one container/div.

here is my code

```
    <html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<style>

#container{
        background: #eeeeee;
        width:330px;
        height:220px;
        margin-top:350px;
        margin-left:700px;
        border:1px solid #000000;
        border-top: 5px solid #000000;
        border-top-left-radius:.5em;
        border-top-right-radius:.5em;
        opacity: .7;
        text-align: center;
        z-index:4;
        position: fixed;
        box-shadow: 8px 8px 2px;
        overflow: hidden;
        font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
    }


a:link    {color:#0000e6; background-color:transparent}

</style>
</head>

<body>

<div id="container"> </div>

<script>


 var container=["random sentence1", "random sentence2", "random sentence3", "random sentence4", "random sentence5", "random sentence6"];

function dieroll() {
    var chance=Math.floor(Math.random()* container.length);

    var roll=document.getElementById("container");
        roll.innerHTML= container[chance];
        roll.style.fontSize="8px";
        roll.style.cursor="pointer";

}
 var text1 =document.createElement('div');
    text1.innerHTML = '<a href="#">the link that would show up beneath the random sentences above';
    text1.style.padding ="10px";
    text1.style.display ="none";



    console.log("array at:"+i);
     var numClicks = 0;
        var x = 5;
    if (numClicks == x) {
        con.innerHTML+=list[i];
        i++;
    } else {
        con.appendChild(text1);
        $(text1).fadeIn(3000);



//console.log(chance)

window.onload=function(){
dieroll();

};



</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can keep track of the number of clicks in your click event and then do something special on the fifth click or even clicks that divide evenly into 5.

Comment: And the problem you're having is...?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way would probably be to use splice to remove an element from the container each time it's randomly selected and shown.

After that, you can check if container is empty (or has "full - 5" number of elements) and then show the link.

Something like this (tried to clean it up a bit, still needs a lot - stuff like CSS rules done in JS should be done in CSS):

```js
var container = ["random sentence1", "random sentence2", "random sentence3", "random sentence4", "random sentence5", "random sentence6"];
var con = document.getElementById("container");
var count = container.length - 5;

function dieroll() {
  if (container.length == count) {
    con.appendChild(text1);
    $(text1).fadeIn(3000);    
  } else {    
    var chance = Math.floor(Math.random() * container.length);
    con.innerHTML = container[chance];
    container.splice(chance, 1);    
  }
}

var text1 = document.createElement('div');
text1.innerHTML = '<a href="#">the link that would show up beneath the random sentences above';

con.addEventListener('click', dieroll);
dieroll();
```

```css
#container {
  background: #eeeeee;
  width: 330px;
  height: 220px;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  border-top: 5px solid #000000;
  border-top-left-radius: .5em;
  border-top-right-radius: .5em;
  opacity: .7;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 4;
  position: fixed;
  box-shadow: 8px 8px 2px;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 8px;
}
#container div {
  font-size: 10px;
  display: none;
}
a:link {
  color: #0000e6;
  background-color: transparent
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar a while back.  Basically I created a `data-` element on the button and decremented it on each click. So in the HTML I had this:

```
<div id="btnCount" data-count="5"></div>
```

Then in the JS (off the top of my head) :

```
var sentences = [
  'sentence 1','sentence 2', // etc
];

$('#btnCount').on( 'click', function() {
  var $t = $(this); 
  var count = $t.data('count') - 1;
  $t.data('count') = count;

  if ( !count ) {
    $t.prop( 'disabled', true ); 
  }
  $t.append( '<br/>'+ sentences[count] );
});
```

Hope that helps.